# In C or C++ can I impose restrictions as to which files can include my header file

Tags: c, include, header-files

In C/C++ I have written a header file which is available to all, however I want to restrict the files that include it. Is there any way I can generate compiler error if my header files is included by an "unauthorized" c/cxx file?

Comment: Perhaps if that's the case you should rethink your coding structure? At least for `c`, I only put interface prototype functions (the visible functions that other files/code intend to call) in the `.h` header file. Any other internal functions meant to be hidden from the outside I declare (as `static`) and define all in the `.c` file. But of course I don't know the details of your situation or if that is even relevant.

Comment: On which basis will you restrict it? I mean, what is the reason for such a requirement?

Comment: It's related to unit testing. I need to expose a class in a header so that it can be mocked in a test, but I don't want anyone else (apart from my implementation) to implement/subclass it.

Answer (score 6):

Of course there is no proper security feature for this (that'd be plain silly), but what you could do is to produce an error in your header file if a certain macro is not present when including the file, so that your `header.h` starts with

```
#ifndef AUTHORIZED_TO_INCLUDE_THE_HEADER
#error "You're not authorized to include this file"
#endif
```

then in the files that include this, do

```
#define AUTHORIZED_TO_INCLUDE_THE_HEADER
#include "header.h"
```